# Ggplot2: Heatmap + Bar chart combination and tweaking

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, heatmap

I'm new to R and am trying to visualise data that is broken down by company and by year for a project at university. I want to try and add bars (as in bar chart bars) to the top and right hand side of the heatmap I've created below, to provide a direct method of comparing count data between the companies (right y axis), and between years for the group as a whole (top x axis).

I know I could probably merge images in Illustrator or something pre-publication, but I know the software is capable of adding together graphics (in a Lattice i think?) and I would like to improve my skills with R and ggplot.

Ideally I would also like to learn to:

1) add the values of each tile superimposed on top

```
geom_text(aes(fill = trialx.m$value, label = trialx.m$value)
```

doesn't seem to work for me?

2) Move the legend so that it was out of the way of the bar plots

3) Adjust the legend size and scale (to account for the data scaling)

4) order the heatmap vertically with the bar sizes

I know this is a lot, but I would appreciate help or advice about any part.

What I'm currently doing:

**Re-scaling**

```
library(ggplot2)
trialx.m <- melt(trialx)
trialx.m <- ddply(trialx.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = scale(value))
```

**Plotting**

```
(p <- ggplot(trialx.m, aes(variable, Company)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "ghostwhite", high = "darkblue"))
```

**Neaten, remove background, rotate text etc.**

```
p + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    opts(legend.position = "", axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 90, hjust = 0, 
        colour = "grey50"))
```

[Here is a dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ixjkifddu9gnnj/stackoverflowsample.txt) to the data I am using:

Comment: I removed the beginning of line console character `>` from your code and put it onto several lines.  In particular please don't make those helping you take the time to remove the `>` from your code.

Comment: Thanks very much: won't happen again!

Comment: I would break this question to several specific questions. I would also include a fully worked out example for each (this means that someone would copy/paste code into R and get prototype objects/figures).